# Creating a .cshtml view within a .Net Standard library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, .net-standard

I'm trying to create a shared class library using **.Net Standard 2.0** which will be used by both Asp.Net Core MVC (2.1) as well as Asp.Net MVC on **.Net Framework 4.5+**.  This is fine for my model classes and I'm able to resolve all the api's that I require so far.  However, I now need to create the shared, partial view that uses the model but I can't seem to find anything useful out there to describe what nuget packages I should reference etc.  When I create the .cshtml view I can't resolve `@model`

I've tried adding the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor` nuget package but it didn't work and I feel I'm missing some essential documentation that explains this better.  If anyone has any ideas, please point me in the right direction or tell me if this is impossible from a .Net Standard project.

**EDIT: Let's forget about .Net Standard.  Is it possible to create a razor view that can be used by both .Net Core and .Net Framework?**

Comment: Are you sure you create a razor view in a class library with target framework .Net Standard?Actually,when i create the class library,it seems has no such choice to create the razor view.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure it's even possible.  There was no option to actually create a Razor View so I added a .html page and renamed the extension and tried to get references etc.

Comment: Yes you can add by selecting Razor class library. so you can add cshtml files